# UserControl does not contain a defination for Application

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, word-addins

I am trying to do a search operation in active word document on a button click.
And getting a error in my code is

**The button is on a custom task pane**

> Error  CS1061  'UserControl1' does not contain a definition for 'Application' and no accessible extension method 'Application' accepting a first argument of type 'UserControl1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  WordAddIn1  c:\users\veroot\source\repos\WordAddIn1\WordAddIn1\UserControl1.cs  29  Active

And the code is

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object findText = textBox1.Text;
        object missing = System.Type.Missing;

        Word.Document document = this.Application.ActiveDocument;
        Word.Range rng = document.Range(0, Type.Missing);


        rng.Find.Highlight = 0;
        rng.Find.Forward = true;
        do
        {
            if (rng.HighlightColorIndex == WdColorIndex.wdYellow)
            {

                rng.HighlightColorIndex = WdColorIndex.wdRed;
                rng.Font.ColorIndex = WdColorIndex.wdBlue;
            }
            int intPosition = rng.End;
            rng.Start = intPosition;
        } while (rng.Find.Execute("", missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, true,
            missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing));
    }
```

Comment: Error is clear. `UserControl1` does not contain a definition for `Application`. Where is Application declared? Can't see in your code, just a usage `this.Application.ActiveDocument`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a VSTO solution it's only possible to use the keyword `this` to refer to the host Office application inside the `ThisAddin` class. In all other classes, including the one for a UserControl, `this` will refer to that class (the UserControl) and have no relation or connection to the host Office application. So in the case of the code shown in the question, `this` refers to the UserControl class.

In order to refer to the Office application in which the VSTO add-in is running it's best to use the `Globals` keyword. For example

```
 Word.Document doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
```

or

```
 Word.Document doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.app.ActiveDocument;
```

where `app` is a class-level field in the `ThisAddin` class - example declaration:

```
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        public Word.Application app;
```

which is assigned in `ThisAddin_Startup` - for example:

```
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        app = this.Application;
```

Comment: Thanks it works for me. One more help please, Can I create a .exe file of my project. So that whenever I run this exe file in other system these task panes will also be visible in that system's Word app. I tried by right click on solution in solution explorer and then build...but I Got   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Please ask this as a new question @AmarMalik. But before you do, it would be a good idea to read the documentation on building and distributing VSTO solutions on MSDN to get a basic idea of the possible approaches and requirements. Then you can ask a more specifically targeted question.